# Mysql row count doesn't match last value entered

Tags: php, mysql

Am having an interesting problem with mysql. I have a table set with the primary key being an auto increment. Recently i made a mistake and had to manually add in 18 records using phpmyadmin as opposed to doing it through the website. Now whats happenend is that there is a discrepancy between what mysql says is the number of records in the table and the last id. Meaning, mysql says there 6935 records in the table, however the last entry in the table has an id of 6917, the extra 18 records that mysql is counting do not exist anywhere. Does anyone know what the problem is? Is this a mysql bug or did I mess up somewhere?

Comment: What does `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourTable` return?

Comment: Where do you get 6935 number from? There are many ways of getting table rowcount in MySQL and not all are accurate.

Comment: Did you perhaps add the values of the auto_increment column manually? The auto_increment is done when the value of the column is undefined, 0 or NULL.

Comment: Should learn what auto_increment actually means ;)

Answer (score 2):

As the id column is auto_increment, if you delete records there will be gaps.

Comment: How does that account for situation when highest auto_increment ID is lower than reported row count? Usually it's the other way round.

Comment: Only way that could happen is if at some time records have been inserted and physically setting the id, this can affect auto increment. i.e. people who delete and then want to re-insert into that row id that has just been deleted. Which as we all know is a no-no.

Comment: @Brian...I didn't delete any records, all i did was insert a set of records using sql. Now I have a situation where mysql count gives me 6935 records yet the last inserted i.d is 6917. Am using 'select count(*) from table' to get the number of records. The interesting thing is that the discrepancy is equivalent to the number of records I inserted!

Comment: Have you checked for duplicate ID's, always need to be very careful manually inserting bulk data.

Answer (score 0):

no there are no bugs in mysql ..

1) you should first check whether data are entered or not.

2) you need to check whether any data that are deleted from table or not..in short you need to check for all auto inc. data.. is it started from 1 and is it in sequence?

Comment: Well... There are a lot of bugs in mysql, but this shouldn't be one of them.